# How to split a string by space, numbers, and quotes in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I am parsing a string in PHP that has the following pattern

```
VARIABLE Key1 Value1 Key2 Value2 Key3 Value3 ...
```

similar to:

```
JOBGRADE 'P' 'Parttime Employee' 'C' 'Customer Support'
```

OR

```
SOMEVARIABLE 1 "Value1" 2 'Value2'
```

This line starts with an unquoted string and can have single or double quoted strings and/or numbers. It can have one to multiple key value pairs.

I need to split the string in 2 ways:

The first to get the unquoted string that is not numeric.

The second to extract the numeric value and/or quoted strings - can be single or dobule

Thus I need

1. JOBGRADE
2. P:Parttime Employee
3. C:Customer Support

OR

1. SOMEVARIABLE
2. 1:Value1
3. 2:Value2

**My Thoughts:**

I thought about splitting the string and iterating through it to test:

for 1: If value is not numeric and not quoted it is the variable name

for 2+: Not sure the easy way to do this because I must detect the difference between the keys and values:

**Question**:

How can I distinguish between the key/value?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Treat it as CSV, and iterate over it to divide it up. The variable is `[0]`, keys are odd starting from `[1]`, values even from `[2]`.

```
var_dump(str_getcsv("JOBGRADE 'P' 'Parttime Employee' 'C' 'Customer Support'",
  ' ', "'"));
```

> ```
> array(5) {
>   [0]=>
>   string(8) "JOBGRADE"
>   [1]=>
>   string(1) "P"
>   [2]=>
>   string(17) "Parttime Employee"
>   [3]=>
>   string(1) "C"
>   [4]=>
>   string(16) "Customer Support"
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank You - great solution. I never thought about using CSV.

Answer (score 1):

first use explode() on the variable string to get all parts seperated by one space: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
$variables = explode("JOBGRADE 'P' 'Parttime Employee' 'C' 'Customer Support'", ' ');
```

//i wouldn't use the first item so remove it, keep as as title for later

```
$var_name = array_shift($variables);
```

//secondly, loop over items (step 2) and add to resulting array the key & value

```
$result = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($variables); $i = $i +2) {
  $result[$variables[$i]] = $variables[$i + 1];
}

print_r($result);
```